# Partial derivatives - simple

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If $f(\mathbf{r})=G(||\mathbf{r}||^2), \mathbf{r}\in \mathbb{R}^n $ and G is just some differentiable function then what would the gradient vector $\nabla f $ be?

I got it as $\nabla f = 2\mathbf{r} G'(||\mathbf{r}||^2) .$ is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out here that since $\nabla f(\mathbf{r})$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{r}$, $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at the origin and containing $\mathbf{r}$.  This satisfies our geometric understanding of the gradient - the level surfaces of $f$ (spheres) are perpendicular to $\nabla f$, and $\nabla f$ points in the direction of greatest increase.